# Expand/Collapse in android-amazing-listview

Tags: android

I am using http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/ for displaying sectioned listview. Can anyone point me to tutorial or links on how can i do an expand/collapse using this library.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't support this feature.